# AS3 POST png to PHP

Tags: actionscript-3, post, png

Have read many similar but no solutions: I'm trying to do something (that i think is) really simple,

Take a photo from gallery or camera - and POST this to a URL. No saving / returning to application. The PNG is just used by the webpage in display and user moves onward.

```
        public function postPicture():void {

        PNGEncoder2.level = CompressionLevel.FAST;  

        var encoder : PNGEncoder2 = PNGEncoder2.encodeAsync(_bitmapData);
        encoder.targetFPS = 12;    

        encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (e):void {
            var png : ByteArray = encoder.png;
            var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
            var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://myurl.com/mypage");
            jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
            jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            jpgURLRequest.data = png;
            navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
        });
    }
```

Also to note, we're getting some odd characters on the end of the URL: C9%90NG

Hunch is that I'm decoding and then not encoding properly before sending i.e. these characters some part of raw image info.

When I test from chrome POST extension with another image, server side stuff works fine so guessing a problem with AS3.

- basically its working when I use chrome to browse > my.png and POST it at the page. Am I missing something with the AS3 png encoder? i.e. how to turn that bmpdata into a 'file' rather than an array of bytes.

thankyou

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.zedia.net/2010/sending-bytearray-image-and-variables-to-server-side-script-as-post-data-in-as3/

Note that the content-type is set to `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use multipart upload. It's a common situation with a well defined standards for that. You can implement it by yourself but it will take some time and efforts.

What I've used before is the [Multipart URLLoader Class](https://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/wiki/MultipartURLLoader) provided by Eugene Zatepyakin, one the best Flash guru's out there :)

It's some kind of old but does the job extremely well. You can add variables, files, whatever content you want to your loader and simply submit it. There are examples with the php side of the thing so you can understand what's going on.

Comment: this worked in part. We got the file to POST but app returned. It carried with it page reply (containing load id) so we just made a second URLloader in same function and passed across the ID's with URL to reclaim via php. Roundabout way of doing it but worked